# JavaScript Array.filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

The `Array.filter()` method is having an asynchronous behavior.
According to the documentation, it seems to me it's not supposed to work that way.

Moreover,it does not allow the reference to a *callback*, as usual in such cases.

I am limited in relation to the use of libraries, but also confuses me, how it reacts that way.

I am not also expert in *ECMAScript*, am i making some mistake?

I just want to filter one array and send the results to a HTML select element as several options.

I have something like this:

```
var selCompanyDeps = departments.filter(fromSelectedCompany);

fillSelect($("#selDeparts"), selCompanyDeps, 'departmentID', 'name', selectedID);

function fromSelectedCompany(value){
    var selectedCompany = $( "#SelComps" ).val();
    return (value.companyID===Number(selectedCompany));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `.filter` is not an async method.

Comment: It does not provide a callback because it is _not_ asynchronous. I cannot discern a question here.

Comment: What does `departments` contain?

Comment: Yes, i saw .filter wasn´t an async method tymeJV, and that's my question Petrichor.

Comment: aduch, departments is a array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array.filter` is not an asynchronous method, but what you appear to be confusing is the order of execution of a JavaScript programme.

When the browser parses your code, the browser will look for named functions and add them to the list of declared names in the current scope (known as [function hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting)).

Therefore, `fromSelectedCompany` is executed **before** you call `fillSelect`, so your code is equivalent to the following:

```
function fromSelectedCompany(value){
    var selectedCompany = $( "#SelComps" ).val();
    return (value.companyID===Number(selectedCompany));
}

var selCompanyDeps = departments.filter(fromSelectedCompany);

fillSelect($("#selDeparts"), selCompanyDeps, 'departmentID', 'name', selectedID);
```

Comment: Thanks toothbrush, i knew about hoisting, i didn't knew there was also function hoisting.

Comment: Great!! It's working. I just put the function as anonymous function inside the .filter, and it solves the question.

One more time, thanks @toothbrush, and thanks everyone who was trying to help


var selCompanyDeps = departments.filter(function (value){
    var selectedCompany = $( "#SelComps" ).val();
    return (value.companyID===Number(selectedCompany));
});

Comment: @PedroGuedes OK, glad to have been of help.